# Calling a value from an array only once

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner in swift and programming in general, so I would love a little help! Once a value is called how do I make it so it cannot be called again?

This is my function that calls a random value.

```
func randomFact() -> String {
    var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(factsArray.count)
    var unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
    var randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)

    return factsArray[randomNumber]
}
```

Here is my viewDidLoad.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var funFactLabel: UILabel!

    let factBook = FactBook()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        funFactLabel.text = factBook.randomFact()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func showFunFact() {
        funFactLabel.text = factBook.randomFact()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete it from the array you can use `Array.removeAtIndex(index: Int) -> Element`

It deletes an index and return it at the same time.

So just replace:

```
return factsArray[randomNumber]
```

With:

```
return factsArray.removeAtIndex(randomNumber)
```

Comment: I received this error `Immutable value of type '[String]' only has mutating members named 'removeAtIndex'`

Comment: Show me how you declare factsArray, it needs to be a var not let

Comment: `struct FactBook {
    var factsArray = ["I have probably 20 values right now","But its to many characters"]`

Comment: Well then you have a syntax error should be: FactBook.factsArray[randomNumber]

Answer (score 0):

@swift for doing what @Arbitur has mentioned your array `factsArray` has to be declared as `var` as `removeAtIndex` is a mutating method (a method which changes `self` in the method body) - if you don't want to use a mutable array you could declare a private variable as `let`and a `NSMutableSet` (or as of Swift 1.2 a `var` as `Set<T>`) and add every random number to it (`myMutableSet.addObject(45)` or `mySet.insert(45)`). Then you can easily check (complexity `O(1)` what means you only have 1 test) if the set contains the element (`mySet.contains(32)`).
Then you have to search for a random number till it isn't part of the set. In the end you can do this (when not using Swift 1.2):

```
let set = NSMutableSet()
func randomFact() -> String {
    let unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(factsArray.count)
    var unsignedRandomNumber: UInt32
    do {
        unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
    } while set.containsObject(unsignedRandomNumber)
    set.addObject(unsignedRandomNumber)
    let randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)
    return factsArray[randomNumber]
}
```